# .NET Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.RestoreTask exception on dotnet publish

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

dotnet publish fails because of following errors caused by Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build. It is a known issue on github but got fixed with version 2.1.76 (https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/514)

I am using the most recent librarymanager version 2.1.175 (VS2017, .NET Core 2.1.509) and am still getting these same errors. While I wait for an answer on github I wanted to ask here if maybe someone is having the same troubles or a workaround?

```
C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018: The "Mi
crosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.RestoreTask" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Team
City\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018: System.
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.LibraryMana
ger.Cache.WebRequestHandler' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationE
xception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Configuration.S
ettings' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load fi
le or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok
en=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HR
ESULT: 0x80131621) [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Configuration.Settings..ctor() [C:\TeamCity\buildAge
nt\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Configuration.Settings..cctor() [C:\TeamCity\buildAg
ent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    ---
End of inner exception stack trace --- [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f8
1a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Configuration.ProxySettings.get_Default() [C:\TeamCi
ty\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cache.WebRequestHandler..cctor() [C:\TeamCity\buildA
gent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    ---
End of inner exception stack trace --- [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f8
1a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.Contracts.Dependencies.Initialize() [C:\TeamCi
ty\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.RestoreTask.Execute() [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\
work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionH
ost.Execute() [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bbac78e917f81a30\Source\...]

C:\Users\teamcitybuild\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.librarymanager.build\2.1.17
5\build\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build.targets(35,9): error MSB4018:    at M
icrosoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost ta
skExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemB
ucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\b
bac78e917f81a30\Source\...]
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is deleting the .packages folder at the solution level for the nuget packages referenced. Then I restored the nuget packages and everything built again.